Track change of commit in nested submodules
If I have a submodule in a git repository and I checkout a commit, the main git repository reflects this change: if I run a git diff I can see the commit change.
However, if I have a submodule (A) inside a submodule (B) inside a git repository (R), if I checkout a specific commit in A, (R) will reflect the change, but if I run git diff I only see the current HEAD of B followed by -dirty.
Is there a way to change this behavior and make R see that A checked out another commit without necessarily having to make a commit in B?

Nope, submodules commits are stored in their direct parent repositories, no way to do that through 2 levels.

@phd That's unfortunate indeed. :(
